# What should be specified as "clientId" and "clientVersion" when using Google's Safe Browsing Lookup API?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api) for Google's Safe Browsing Lookup API says that the request body should include "clientId" and "clientVersion" fields.

```
  {
    "client": {
      "clientId":      "yourcompanyname",
      "clientVersion": "1.5.2"
    },
    "threatInfo": {
      "threatTypes":      ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
      "platformTypes":    ["WINDOWS"],
      "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"],
      "threatEntries": [
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck1.org/"},
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck2.org/"},
        {"url": "http://www.urltocheck3.com/"}
      ]
    }
  }
```

What is meant by the "client"? Do they mean the version of [Google's Safebrowsing Client Library for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Safebrowsing.v4) or do they mean the name and version of the app being developed? I am quite confused. Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Comment: The [documentation you linked to](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api#client-information) literally tells you what it is.

Comment: Does the company name mean app name?

Comment: " You can choose any name for the client ID, but we suggest you choose a name that represents the true identity of the client, such as your company name"

Comment: Damn, you are right, it was literally there. Thank you very much